# How to remove set of string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

On the following string I want to remove `sort=*`. I can get this done by run loop over it But want to get it done using regex which is new to me.

So start point should be "sort" and end point should be '&' and sort value could be `*`

I have created this one but dont how to add end point

```
string.replace((sort=*)\w,'')



"category_id=249&sort=name&category_filter=15&"
```

to

```
"category_id=249&category_filter=15&"
```

Comment: Modern browsers provide [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) to work with query strings.

Comment: You can build string by chosen properties from something object, it could be more declarative approach than editing existing string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca use this regex instead `(sort=.*?&)`, which can match every thing from `sort=` until the first occurrence of `&`

## regex demo

**Output**

```
category_id=249&category_filter=15&
```